# Xamarin BindableProperty in custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a bindable property in a custom control in order to set a property from the xaml code. However, it seems like my property always will get the default value that I've specified for the bindable property.

My xaml code:

```
<controls:MyView ID="4" />
```

My code behind:

```
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IDProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                    nameof(ID),
                                    typeof(int),
                                    typeof(MyView),
                                    15);
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
             return (int)GetValue(IDProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IDProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private MyViewViewModel viewModel;

    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new MyViewViewModel() {};
        BindingContext = viewModel; 
    }
}
```

I expect that my property should get value 4 in this example, but it always get the default value 15. Should the property be set in the constructor or later?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share all the code of your control and especially constructor? Maybe you set the BindingContext incorrectly ...

Comment: @EvZ I've updated the code above.

Comment: Why do you have a ViewModel embedded into your CustomControl?

Comment: It's not working because the `BindingContext` is pointing to a `MyViewViewModel` object. If you want to make it works change `BindingContext = viewModel; ` by `BindingContext = this`. BTW, the `MyViewViewModel` field is not necessary. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you embed a `ViewModel` inside your custom control?
 It is weird and even wrong. The idea behind a custom control is that you could reuse and bind it to the parent's `ViewModel`. Think of a simple `Button` control, it is reusable by simple placing it on the screen and setting the `BindableProperties` like `Text`, `Command` and etc. It is working because it's `BindingContext` by default is the same as it's parent.

In your case you sort of isolate your control from any modifications, since you set the `BindingContext` to a private custom `ViewModel` class. You have to rethink your solution.

It should be as simple as:

```
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IDProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                    nameof(ID),
                                    typeof(int),
                                    typeof(MyView),
                                    15);
    public int ID
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(IDProperty);
        set => SetValue(IDProperty, value);
    }

    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see it's too late, but i have been suffering for a while now, that - for a reason that i don't know - a ContentView(Custom view element) won't bind when you set it's *BindingContext* property in any way other than this:

```
<ContentView x:Class="mynamespace.CustomViews.MyView"
....
 x:Name="this">
```

then on the main container element (in my case a frame) set the *BindingContext*

```
<Frame BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
....>
```

Setting the *BindingContext* in the *constructor* - in *MyView.xaml.cs* - does not work, while this way - and other ways - work in binding a *View* to another class (a view model), it does not - i repeat - work in binding ContentView to its code_behind.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

In you xaml , do

```
<controls:MyView ID="{Binding Id}" />
```

And then in ViewModel, Create a porperty called Id

```
public int Id {get; set;} = 4;
```

Comment: But then I don't need the bindableproperty... What I want to do is to assign the control property from the xaml. I intend to have a couple of controls with different ID numbers, like: <controls:MyView ID="4" /> and <controls:MyView ID="5" />

Comment: Yes, I do. But the primary purpose is to set an id on the control which is necessary for the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Bindable property if your are not binding , Just Create a Normal Property of type int With ID as property name.And then you can assign the ID from XAML.(Intellisense will also show the ID property)

```
public int ID
{
    get;set;
}
```

Comment: Ok, it doesn't seems to work either. Yes I can see it through Intellisense, but the value of the property is always zero no matter what value I assign.

Comment: same if it's a string, the value is null